# How to create RCP plugin which is used in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

This question is seems to be immature question, but I didn't find any satisfactory solution for this from long time.

I want to deliver a plugin of my RCP application.
I am able to create a plugin which works as a stand alone application [here](http://cyberpen.wordpress.com/2008/06/16/convertion-of-a-plugin-to-a-standalone-rcp-application/)
But still struggles to find how to create a RCP plugin which other developers can add in there own eclipse and start using it.

Any reference is appreciated.

Regards,
Mandar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html
hope this helps.